# sum the numbers in different model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

i have two models Vote and Option,each with column "total" and "quantity".
**(Vote has_many:options)**

I want to implement like this initially:

> Option.quantities.each{ |quantity| total+=quantity}
>
> Vote.total=total

how to implement that??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you asking for an alternate implementation? Or for something else? You can do the same thing with `Enumerable::inject`, for example:

```
class Vote < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :options
  def calculate_total
    total = self.options.inject(0) { |sum, vote| sum += vote.quantity }
    save!
  end
end
```

In this way, the Vote total is calculated and saved every time `calculate_total` is called.